# Loop through .nc and .txt files simultaneously

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to loop through all .nc and .txt files simultaneously, that are in current directory. For each loop the files .nc and .txt have exactly the same name, it is just that ending (.nc and .txt) that changes.

So far I have:

```
for f in *.nc *.txt
do  
    echo $f
    cdo setgrid,${f%.txt}.txt  ${f%.nc}.nc ${f%.nc}_WITH_BOUNDS.nc
    cdo remapcon,/mnt/my_dir/static.txt ${f%.nc}_WITH_BOUNDS.nc ${f%.nc}_WITH_BOUNDS_latlon.nc
done
```

Comment: So you want to (say) loop through all the `*.nc` files and process them using the "paired" `.txt` file?

Comment: Exactly! Each .nc file should be processed using the .txt file which has the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Try looping across the `.nc` files only, and create the `.txt` file names from it:

```
for FNC in *.nc
 do     FN=${FNC%.nc}
        echo $FNC, $FN
        cdo setgrid,"$FN".txt "$FN".nc "$FN"_WITH_BOUNDS.nc
        cdo remapcon,/mnt/my_dir/static.txt "$FN"_WITH_BOUNDS.nc "$FN"_WITH_BOUNDS_latlon.nc
  done
```

You may want to check if the .txt counterpart exists before running the `cdo` commands.